# Merging vs Reintergration

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, reintegration

In svn, what is the difference between **merging** changes from a Branch back to Trunk and **reintegrating** changes from a Branch to Trunk? Does this result in the same result with no future problems?

Comment: Question has already been answered on stack overflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575325/svn-merge-a-range-of-revisions-vs-reintegrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reintegration is not separate operation - it's subtype of merge.

Reintegrate merging is different from the 'normal' merging: It carefully replicates only those changes unique to the source **Merge From** compared to the local working copy (**Merge To** in common case)

Read also [Why is --reintegrate needed for svn 1.5 merging?](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2008-05/0808.shtml)