# Reintegrate a branch without merging in trunk changes

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, feature-branch

I use tortoise svn. But I'm fairly new to svn in general. I have some experience with git though.

In the docu it says

> Reintegrate a branch
>
> This method covers the case when you have made
>   a feature branch as discussed in the Subversion book. 
>   All trunk changes have been ported to the feature 
>   branch, week by week, and now the feature is complete
>   you want to merge it back into the trunk.

As far as I understood this: 
The normal workflow for a feature branch would be, to make a feature branch, do developing on it, frequently merge in ranges of revisions from bugfixes on the trunk branch. When the feature is done, do the final merge of the trunk changes, and then reintegrate the branch into trunk.

So I have some questions:

1. Is this workflow correct
2. What happens if I don't merge in the changes from the trunk branch before reintegrating the feature branch
3. What happens if I do a normal merge from a fully updated feature branch to a trunk branch
4. Why is this so complicated, svn is meant to be more user friendly than git, but especially merging, where you have to specify the revisions to merge into the feature branch, and choosing from different merging options seems way more complicated than the equivalent git functionality (I have to use svn in my company, because the other developers use it, they do no branching though), unless I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 8):

First a quick lesson on how merging works and works for almost all version control systems.

The standard Merge is a *three way merge*. In this, you're comparing the two versions with the *last common ancestor* of the two versions. For example, I branch from trunk. The version on the trunk before the branch is the *last common ancestor*.

The purpose is to be able to see the changes on one *stream* vs. the changes on the other *stream*. (A stream could be a specific branch or the trunk). For example, If  I'm merging from trunk to the branch, I want to make sure I don't overwrite my specific branch changes with those lines on the trunk.

The comparison with the last common ancestor allows you to see only the changes that took place on the trunk since that branch point.

This presents a problem when I go backwards from my previous merges. For example, I am finished with my feature branch, and want all of the feature changes back on trunk. This is a problem because I've merged all of my trunk changes onto the branch. That means my branch's *stream* shows that I made changes on the branch, and these should be merged into trunk. But, these changes are already on the trunk! To handle this issue, you can force a two-way merge. In this case, you're only comparing the heads of the two separate streams with each other and copying all of the difference from one stream to another.

---

Now how Subversion handles merges:

First, Subversion loves cherry pick mergin. Subversion allows you to specify which revision you want to merge. For example, I have a branch, found a bug and fixed it on the branch. I can now merge that particular revision or set of revisions that contain my bug fix. When you cherry pick in Subversion, you are doing a three way merge, but you are only considering the changes represented in those particular *cherry picked* versions and not all changes on either the trunk or branch.

In fact, Subversion almost always does cherry pick merges even if you don't specify cherry picked revisions. Subversion tracks what revisions were merged via the `svn:mergeinfo` property. Let's say I branched at revision 100, and now I'm merging my trunk changes into my branch. The last revision on trunk is now revision 150. Subversion considers you're doing a cherry pick of all the versions on trunk from revision 100 (but not including version 100) to revision 150. Next time I do a merge from my trunk to my branch (let's say the last change on my trunk is now 175), Subversion will *cherry pick* changes on trunk since (but not including 150) to revision 175.

Note that when I specify cherry pick revisions for the merge, I am allowed to go back and forth between my branch and my trunk without any problems. If I merge from my feature branch to my trunk, I could specify the revisions on my feature branch where I implemented the feature and skip the changes on my feature branch that were the results of merge from trunk.

The problem, only comes when I let Subversion handle the *cherry picking*. When I merge from my trunk to my branch, Subversion tracks the revisions of my trunk that are on my branch. However, Subversion has no way of knowing which revisions on my feature branch were the results of my trunk merges.

Thus, when I merge my feature branch back into trunk, Subversion will consider all unmerged revisions -- including those revisions that were the result of trunk to branch merges, and tries to merge all of those revisions back into my trunk.

To handle this, Subversion has a special merge called a *reintegration* merge. I merge my last set of changes on my trunk into my branch, then when I merge my branch into my trunk, I want my trunk and branch to be identical. Thus, Subversion wants to do a two-way merge and make trunk and the branch match.

In older versions of Subversion, I would have to manually specify that I am doing this two-way merge with the `--reintegration` parameter on the `svn merge` command.

Subversion's merge tracking also lead to an interesting problem with reusing a feature branch. Let's say I do my last set of merges from trunk to my branch. The last revision on trunk and the last revision in Subversion was revision 100. When I merge my changes from the trunk onto my branch, I now create revision 101 on my branch. The `svn:mergeinfo` property on that branch shows that I've merged all of my changes up to revision 100 from trunk only my branch.

Now, I do my *reintegration* merge, commit the changes, and create revision 102 on my trunk.

Now, I do more work on my trunk, (let's say revision 103) and I want to merge those changes onto my feature branch.

What was that last revision I merged from trunk to my feature branch? Looking at `svn:mergeinfo`, I see it's revision 100. And since that last merge from trunk to branch, there are now two new revisions on trunk that have not yet been merged into my feature branch: Revision 102 and Revision 103.

So, Subversion will do it's *cherry picking* and attempt to merge the changes contained in revisions 102 and revision 103 onto my feature branch. But wait... Revision 102 are all of my feature branch changes being merged onto trunk! I'm going to be reapplying those feature changes onto my feature branch!

There are two ways to handle this: Method One: Once you do a *reintegration* merge, you should never ever use that feature branch again. Delete it. Lock it away in a nunnery. Never speak its name again. If I need that feature branch once more, I should create a new feature branch from trunk.

The other way is to munge `svn:mergeinfo` on the feature branch to make Subversion know that revision 102 on trunk has already been *merged* into my feature branch. You can do this with the `--record-only` parameter:

```
$ svn co $REPO/branches/feature/myproj
$ cd myproj
$ svn merge --record-only -r102 $REPO/trunk/myproj
```

As you can see, all of this manual effort -- knowing when to use that `--reintegration` switch and understanding what happens when you do a *reintegration* merge -- caused confusion. Therefore, newer versions of Subversion (I believe since revision 1.8) now attempt to handle this for you.

If you're using Subversion 1.8 as a client, you never have to specify the `--reintegration` parameter. Subversion will programmatically determine whether you are doing a typical three way merge or a *reintegration* merge and act accordingly.

If I attempt to do what Subversion considers a *reintegration merge*, and I have not yet merged all of my trunk revisions into my feature branch, Subversion will warn me and not let me do the merge. If I reuse a feature branch once I do my *reintegration* merge, Subversion is suppose to detect this and automatically handle the issue of branch reuse after reintegration. (Sometimes it does't quite work. However, Subversion won't let you reuse the feature branch after a reintegration merge, but might give you an error and you may have to manually do the `--record-only` merge.)

---

So in Subversion, how should you do your workflow?

Unlike Git where each bug and feature should be on its own branch least you need to merge that bugfix or feature onto multiple branches, you an do almost all of your work right off the trunk (or whatever branch you like). In most Subversion shops, branching is only done for a candidate release. That is, I'm about to do a release, I branch for that release. Some developers work on the release, others continue their work on trunk.

If a bug is found on trunk, it can be fixed on trunk, and that revision or set of revisions where that bug was fixed can be merged onto the release branch. Or, if you find a bug on the feature branch that needs to be fixed on the trunk, you can fix that bug on the feature branch and merge that revision or set of revisions onto trunk.

It's simple, straight forward, and easy to implement.

This doesn't mean you can't branch for a feature. In fact, sometimes you have to. Imagine a feature that's being implemented deep into the future. You don't want those changes on trunk. In that case, create the feature branch, and merge your trunk changes regularly onto that feature branch. Just remember that there may be issues when you merge that feature back into trunk. As long as you understand what's going on. It's no problem.

And, if you want to go hog wild and create a gazillion branches for each feature and bug, you can do that too. However, I recommend you use Subversion 1.8 which will do that for you.

Comment: Damm.You could write an svn book.

Answer (score 0):

1. More or less
2. The point of frequent merges from trunk to your feature branch is that it's **piece-meal**: small and manageable. When conflicts arise, they can be fixed with changes fresh in your mind. Nothing "bad" will happen if you don't merge changes from trunk to feature branch before reintegrating. Just that you will have to deal with the **merge of all changes all at once**, which will likely produce a **lot of conflicts**, and you may not even remember the parts of the code that are causing conflicts, making you re-learn that code and spending more time on resolving the conflicts. If your trunk and feature branch are synced daily, it may be as simple as an extra 5 minutes per day to perform the sync and clear conflicts. If you leave that till the end of the feature branch, you may spend a full day or two resolving all conflicts at once.
3. See [Reintegrate a branch vs merge a range of revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758249/reintegrate-a-branch-vs-merge-a-range-of-revision), [What are the differences between merging a range of revisions vs. reintegrate in SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575325/svn-merge-a-range-of-revisions-vs-reintegrate) and [Consequences of not using --reintegrate with svn merge back to trunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691897/consequences-of-not-using-reintegrate-with-svn-merge-back-to-trunk)
4. SVN is more user friendly than git. It is centralized, has great windows GUI in the form of TortoiseSVN. The latest version of TortoiseSVN removed the "reintegrate" option, as it automatically figures that out when you do so. When you checkmark revisions for merging it will store this information in SVN, so next time you can easily **visually** see what revisions have already been checked in, and so on.