# What happens if there is a commit between the last merge and the reintegration merge in SVN?

Tags: svn, svn-merge-reintegrate

Normally, when reintegrating an SVN branch into trunk, we create a history like this:

```
trunk   A---B---D---F---H
             \       \ /
branch        C---E---G---X
```

where `G` is a merge, `H` is the reintegration merge, and `X` delete the feature branch. I also get that there is a difference in the merge algorithm that SVN uses for `G` and `H`. So far, so good.

However, one thing is bugging me: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6575565/2445184) cites SVN documentation on what happens with a reintegration merge as: "And in fact, it does this by comparing the latest trunk tree with the latest branch tree: the resulting difference is exactly your branch changes!"

Since `trunc + changes from branch = trunc + (branch - trunk) = branch`, I conclude that the recorded state after a reintegration merge is always exactly the same as the recorded state at the end of the branch.

Now consider this history:

```
trunk   A---B---D---F---H---I
             \        \   /
branch        C---E-----G-----X
```

With the reasoning above, I'd assume that the changes from commit H are simply lost if `I` is a reintegration merge. Is this correct, or is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion know that last sync revision is `F`, so it calculate difference between `trunk@F` and `branch@G` and then apply it to working copy.

If destination working copy checked out revision `F`, then reintegrate will go smooth(without conflicts) and after that you update wc to `H` (possible conflicts) and be able to commit.

If destination working copy checked out revision `H`, then reintegrate merge will be performed on top of `H` (in this case possible conflicts during merge)

In any case nothing will be lost.